# How to find out which stored procedure is using the specific column of a specific table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FullName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Employees 
(
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FullName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
);
```

If I have used the `FullName` column of the `Customers` table in any stored procedure, then I want to get all those stored procedure names by searching with `ColumnName = 'FullName'` and `TableName = 'Customers'`.

I don't need those stored procedure names where I have used the `FullName` column from the `Employees` table.

Is it possible to write a script for this in SQL Server?

**NB:** In my search criteria I want to search with column name and Table name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `sys.sql_dependencies` which has been deprecated, you can use the newer `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` instead.

> Unfortunately, after some testing, it turns out that `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` and `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` do not return information on column-level dependencies.

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id),
       OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id)
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name), 'OBJECT') d
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON c.object_id = d.referenced_id
    AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id
    AND c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Customers')
    AND c.name = 'FullName'
WHERE o.type IN ('FN','TF','IF','P','V','TR');  -- scalar, multi-line and inline funcs, procs, views, triggers
```

Comment: +1 for providing non deprecated option. One downside or maybe upside of this is that it will return irrelevant errors if run in a DB that already has broken legacy cruft. (e.g. with this object in place `CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LegacyNonsense]() RETURNS nvarchar(35) 
AS
BEGIN
 RETURN (SELECT Foo FROM Bar)
END`

Comment: I don't get any errors from that. What error should it give? What is legacy or broken about that, other than missing schema and table references?

Comment: It references tables and columns that don't exist. Which IME is quite common for any database that has been up and running for a few years (hence "legacy cruft") - so then running the query still produces results but also produces error messages https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJobp.png

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks a lot for saving my life. Actually I needed this query when we are changing the column name of table. Before using this query which is provided by you, I have to check all the stored procedure, functions, triggers and views to find where we have used that column of that specific table. Now its saving lots of my time and making life easier.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.sql_dependencies` is deprecated but whilst it is still around you can use

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(d.object_id),
       OBJECT_NAME(d.object_id)
FROM   sys.sql_dependencies d
       INNER JOIN sys.columns c
               ON c.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
                  AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id
WHERE  d.class = 0
       AND d.referenced_major_id = object_id('dbo.Customers')
       AND c.name = 'FullName'
```

This has a lot of advantages over a text search in that you won't get issues where procedures contain both the string `Customers` and `FullName` but as comments or some other context that would yield a false positive. It also handles cases where procedures contain `*` rather than mentioning the name explicitly.

If you use dynamic SQL you will likely need to fall back to a more painful text search though.

I'd probably end up using a hybrid approach to cover all angles as below so I can eliminate the need to actually review the text of definite dependencies found in `sys.sql_dependencies` and just have to manually review the "Possibles"

```
WITH Candidates AS
(
SELECT d.object_id, 0 AS Source
FROM   sys.sql_dependencies d
       INNER JOIN sys.columns c
               ON c.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
                  AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id
WHERE  d.class = 0
       AND d.referenced_major_id = object_id('dbo.Customers')
       AND c.name = 'FullName'
UNION ALL
SELECT m.object_id, 1 AS Source
FROM sys.sql_modules m
WHERE m.definition LIKE '%Customers%' AND (m.definition LIKE '%FullName%' OR m.definition LIKE '%*%')
)
SELECT SchemaName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id),
       ModuleName = OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
       Confidence = IIF(MIN(Source) = 0, 'High', 'Possible')
FROM Candidates
GROUP BY object_id
```

Comment: Why not `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`?

Comment: @Charlieface - That doesn't have the same "per column" detail

Comment: @Charlieface https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfqca.png

Comment: Seems you're right. Also `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` doesn't. But `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` *does* return column-level info

Comment: @Charlieface - True. TBH I forgot about that one. That's a pain to use though as it needs to be `CROSS APPLY`-ed from a result with potential referencing objects and can end up throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

The table `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` will give you the information that you are after. You can check its reference in the Microsoft website: [SQL Server 2019 Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I like to complete this with a text search. To do this you can export all your Store Procedures scripts as flat files and then you search in the files.

You can use the function "Find in Files" of Notepad++ to find references. You will need to consider that column may have been referred using different formats: ."Date_Id", .[Date_Id] or .Date_Id.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the dynamic aspect of SQL (links between objects are not always known at the moment of creating the object except in the case of using SCHEMABINDING directive) links are completed when "executing" the object. So the only way to be shure that you will find all objetc with a reference of another object or attribute of an object is to use an internal standard for naming...

[Personnaly I use this convention for my business development (actually I do that for clubmed...)](https://www.sqlspot.com/sites/sqlspot.com/IMG/pdf/Norme_de_developpement_BD.pdf)... But it is in french !

To summarize:

1. All tables have a name beginning by T_ and ending with a unique
   trigram (unique in the table list). Example : T_CUSTOMER_CST
2. All views have a name beginning by V_ and ending with a unique
   trigram (unique in the view list). Example : V_CUSTOMER_CST
3. All table function have a name beginning by F_ and ending with a
   unique trigram (unique in the function list). Example :
   F_CUSTOMER_CST
4. All internal data colums of an table have a name beginning with the
   trigram of the table. Example for table T_CUSTOMER_CST the name of a
   customer is CST_NAME, the ID is CST_ID.
5. All external data columns (foreign key) keep the original name, and
   if it exists more than one reference, be completed by some
   distinguishing element. Example for table T_JOURNEY_JRN the id of
   the origin town an the target town comming from table T_TOWN_TWN are
   TWN_ID_STARTS and TWN_ID_ENDS

And so on...

So to find any impact of changing the definition of a column in routines (procs, triggers, functions, view...) the query to run is :

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.sql_modules
WHERE  definition LIKE '%TWN?_ID%' ESCAPE '?'
```

This will find all object containing a column nammed TWN_ID.